# Getting started with Slackware as a web server

Tags: webserver, slackware

I'm wondering what would be the path for an Arch user to get into slackware hosted on a VPS intended to use as a web server?
I like the approach that Slackware takes (like Arch), and the fact that so many small VPS (Memory < 512MB) support it, but I can't find any decent info on actually getting started with it on Google as a web host.

So if you have any tips or guides on how to get started with the subject they'll be greatly appreciated!.

Answer (score 2):

Slackware doesn't make a lot of changes to any given software.  Apache httpd is installed right-out-of-the-box, so all you'd really have to do is:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.httpd  # Apache starts at boot
apachectl start
```

And then start filling in `/srv/httpd/htdocs/`

I should add that the Apache configuration file(s) appear in /etc/httpd/